# Elasticsearch mac address search/mapping

Tags: search, indexing, mapping, elasticsearch, mac-address

I can't get the mac address search to return proper results when I'm doing partial searches (half octect). I mean, if I look for the exact mac address I get results but if try to search for partial search like "00:19:9" I don't get anything until I complete the octet.

Can anyone point out which mapping should I use to index it or kind of search query should I use??

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/ap-test
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/ap-test

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/1 -d '
{
  "user" : "James Earl",
  "macaddr" : "00:19:92:00:71:80"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/2 -d '
{
  "user" : "Earl",
  "macaddr" : "00:19:92:00:71:82"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/3 -d '
{
  "user" : "James Edward",
  "macaddr" : "11:19:92:00:71:80"
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/ap-test/_refresh'
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/_mapping?pretty
```

When I to find exact matches I get them correctly....

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/_search -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query":"\"00\\:19\\:92\\:00\\:71\\:80\""
        }
    }
}'

# RETURNS:

{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.57534903,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "ap-test",
        "_type": "devices",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.57534903,
        "_source": {
          "user": "James Earl",
          "macaddr": "00:19:92:00:71:80"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

HOWEVER, I need to be able to match partial mac addresses searches like this:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/_search -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query":"\"00\\:19\\:9\""
        }
    }
}'

# RETURNS 0 instead of returning 2 of them 

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

SO, What mapping should I use? Is there a better query string to accomplish this? BTW, what's the difference between using 'query_string' and 'text'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found and easier way to make it work.

Elasticsearch query options are confusing sometimes because they have so many options...

- [**query_string**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/): has a full-fledged search with a myriad of options and
  wildcard uses.
- [**match**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/): is simpler and doesn't require wildcard
  characters, or other “advance” features. This one it's great to use
  it in search boxes because chances of it failing are very small if not non-existent.

So, that said. This is the one that work the best in most cases and didn't required customized mapping.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/_search -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
            "_all" : "00:19:92:00:71:8"
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't defined a mapping at all, which means elasticsearch will guess off your datatypes and use the standard mappings.

For the field macaddr, this will be recognised as a string and the standard string analyzer will be used. This analyzer will break up the string on whitespace and punctuation, leaving you with tokens consisting of pairs of numbers. e.g. `"00:19:92:00:71:80"` will get tokenized to `00` `19` `92` `00` `71` `80`. When you search the same tokenization will happen.

What you want is to define an analyzer which turns `"00:19:92:00:71:80"` into the tokens `00` `00:` `00:1` `00:19` etc...

Try this:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/ap-test  -d '
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_edge_ngram_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer" : {
                "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                    "type" : "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram" : "2",
                    "max_gram" : "17"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/_mapping  -d '
{
    "devices": {
        "properties" {
            "user": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "macaddr": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer" : "my_edge_ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Put the documents as before, then search with the query **specifically aimed at the field**:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/ap-test/devices/_search -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query":"\"00\\:19\\:92\\:00\\:71\\:80\"",
            "fields": ["macaddr", "user"]
        }
    }
}'
```

As for your last question, the `text` query is deprecated.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! It look like the edgeNGram is mapping I needed. However, adding "default_field:macaddr"  breaks the search on other fields like "user". So, now if I search for "James" it won't return results. If I remove "default_field" works for "user" column but not for "macaddr" column. I need it to work for both in one query. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited my answer, use the `"fields": [...]` parameter of `query_string`. Go [read the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/) and get used to how they are laid out, will make your life a lot easier!!!

Comment: It works but I will have to define the all the fields, which is cumbersome with large number of columns. I found that 'match_phrase_prefix' does what I needed even without the nGram mapping. Thanks for the link that's how I found that option :)

Comment: That's a good find! Just take on board, that it will be doing an expansion of the last term in the phrase (like a wildcard search). This is fine as all your terms are only 2 characters (an octet), but will be slower than an edgeNgramed search if the terms are longer.